# Statement Blocks in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm coming from a background in JavaScript and as I'm trying to learn T-SQL I'm bothered by the organization of the code.

Right now I'm looking at [Example A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql#examples) in the documentation for the `WHILE` loop and it's written as such:

```
WHILE (SELECT AVG(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) < $300  
BEGIN  
   UPDATE Production.Product  
      SET ListPrice = ListPrice * 2  
   IF (SELECT MAX(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) > $500  
      BREAK  
   ELSE  
      CONTINUE  
END  
PRINT 'Too much for the market to bear';
```

There's nothing complex about it. It's easy to read and understand but it just looks unorganized to me due to lack of {} to define blocks. If I were to be writing the same kind of thing in JavaScript it'd look like:

```
WHILE (SELECT AVG(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) < $300  {
    UPDATE Production.Product  
    SET ListPrice = ListPrice * 2  
    IF (SELECT MAX(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) > $500  {
        BREAK;
    } ELSE {
        CONTINUE;
    }
};
console.log('Too much for the market to bear');
```

---

So my question is: Is there anything built into T-SQL (for SQL Server) that lets you organize your code in this way that doesn't have an impact on the code itself? Like can I add () or {} to break up blocks?

Comment: I mean, the `{ .. }` are replaced with `BEGIN .. END` respectively. It's just that they are not needed when there is just one line

Comment: Talk to Microsoft @SeanLange (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql). Although I'm pretty sure it's just there to show how the loop works.

Comment: I think you missed my point. I know the syntax. What I was saying is that I would write this without a loop because it isn't needed.

Comment: So something along the following lines... `UPDATE Product
SET ListPrice *= (SELECT POWER(2, FLOOR(CASE
                                            WHEN AVG(ListPrice) >= 300
                                              THEN 0
                                            WHEN LOG(300.0 / AVG(ListPrice), 2) > LOG(500.0 / MAX(ListPrice), 2)
                                              THEN LOG(300.0 / AVG(ListPrice), 2)
                                            ELSE LOG(500.0 / MAX(ListPrice), 2)
                                          END))
                    FROM   Product p)`

Comment: @SeanLange I didn't miss your point, I ignored it because it was irrelavent to my question. I wasn't asking about how to properly write a loop or whether it was necessary. I can make such a determination on my own. That has nothing to do with syntax or blocks. If you have no comments for the actual question, don't answer. All you did was come off as condescending commenting on an example piece of code that's only used to illustrate the use of nesting IF statements in WHILE loops, not for it to be practical.That it isn't practical doesn't even matter as it had nothing to do with what I asked.

Comment: Wasn't intended to be condescending but loops in t-sql should be avoided whenever possible because they are horrible for performance. Loops are great in programming languages but t-sql is declarative and looping is a mindset that is challenging to unlearn when coming from a programming background. For the question at hand you could just as easily skip the {} in javascript when the contents are a single line, just like skipping the begin/end in t-sql blocks.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL, `BEGIN` and `END` are the closing and ending blocks for any set of statements
You can however write code like below and it will be legal

```
WHILE (SELECT AVG(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) < $300  --{
BEGIN
    UPDATE Production.Product  
    SET ListPrice = ListPrice * 2  
    IF (SELECT MAX(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) > $500  --{
        BREAK;
    --} 
   ELSE --{
        CONTINUE;
    --}
--};
END
```

a verbose code would be like

```
WHILE (SELECT AVG(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) < $300  --{
BEGIN
    UPDATE Production.Product  
    SET ListPrice = ListPrice * 2  
    IF (SELECT MAX(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) > $500  --{
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END
    --} 
   ELSE --{
   BEGIN
        CONTINUE;
   END
    --}
--};
END
```